# What AVERAGEX function does in this context?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate monthly trend KPI over last 6 months. Whether it is positive or negative.

So I have columns:  `Current Month Premium, Previous Month Premium, Month Over Month`

Then I am using `AVERAGEX` and `DATESBETWEEN` functions to find out whether trend is positive or negative.

```
WP 6M Trend = 
VAR LastEffDate = LASTDATE(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate])
RETURN 
AVERAGEX(
    DATESBETWEEN(
        dim_Date[Date],
        DATEADD(STARTOFMONTH(LastEffDate), -5,MONTH),  //creates rolling 6 months window [Ttl WP] and [PreviousMonthWP]
        ENDOFMONTH(LastEffDate)
        ),
        [MoM WP]
        )
```

But I don't quiet understand how `-72` exactly calculated here?

So I need to understand to know whether it is correct or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your avergex is evaluating the last period in your dataset due the the fact that your LastEffDate calculates the last available date in a dataset or subset. As the total line refers to the entire context of all the data in your table, it computes the last date similarly to the last period you calculated, effectively the same calculation as the month august in this case.